# Is it possible to load a one-many relationship with DB::table in Laravel 8?

Tags: database, laravel, relationship

I have this DB::table query, which it get list of branches, and what I need to do further is to get list of items for each branch as well, I can use join, but to respect optimization I was wondering if this can be achieved via loading relationship? I did some googling however, but did not find a satisfaction [related response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397135/laravel-5-dbtable-and-relationship-in-eloquent) yet.

```
$branches = DB::table('branches')
->join('branche_main_info', 'branches.id', '=', 'branche_main_info.business_id')
->where('branche_main_info.status', 'approved');
```

And the relationship is:

```
// Relation ship with Items
public function ItemsList(){
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

Now what I am trying to get out of this is:

```
$branches->with('ItemsList')->get();
```

Related Models:

```
// Relationship with details table.
public function approvedItemDetails(){
    return $this->hasOne(ItemDetails::class, 'item_id')->where('details_status', 'approved')->latest();
}

// Relation ship with Items
public function ItemsList(){
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

Comment: Post your model definitions

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid The model for branches or the Items?

Comment: Model for branche_main_info, branches  and items, in short all model that are involved in your query

Comment: But $branches->with('ItemsList')->get(); is optimized and working? what is the problem then, that first query is not that pragmatic.

Comment: @mrhn Here is the result 
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

Comment: I decided to go with Eloquent for now due to urgency of the task, So instead of DB::table('branches') I used, Branch::with('ItemsList') ...... ->get(), and this worked in my case.